# Pythonic formatting from 1 to 01

Tags: python

I want to be able to be able to format date/time input for my function.

Currently, I have a function that basically appends a 0 to a number if it is only 1 digit long.

```
def format_num(str(num)):
    if len(num) < 2:
        return "0" + num
    return num
```

I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Here you go: python -c 'print("%02d" % 1)'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: "Format for a datetime" - why not [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) your datetime object  (`%d` or `%m` for day / month)

Comment: Generally speaking: `format(num, '02d')` or `str(num).zfill(2)`, but for *datetime* objects there are better ways still. Do you have `datetime` objects here?

Comment: @Javier: isn't the '%' operator deprecated in favor of `str.format`?

Comment: AFAIK, both are supported. .format can also do that as Paulo referenced.

Comment: @PauloScardine - It is not officially *deprecated* (yet), but  its use is discouraged in favor of `str.format`.  I wouldn't be surprised if it is eventually removed from the language though (Python 4 maybe?).  New code should use `str.format`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use the string method `zfill` to pad the strings with zeros to a specified width. Specify a width of 2:

```
>>> '1'.zfill(2)
'01'
```

Strings longer than one character won't be touched:

```
>>> '31'.zfill(2)
'31'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> ["{:02}".format(num) for num in (1,22,333)]
['01', '22', '333']
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec for more on the syntax understood by the `format` method.

Comment: Don't use `str.format()` where a simple `format()` would do. No need to parse out `{...}` placeholders and map to arguments that way. `format(num, '02')` or `format(num, '02d')`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters TMTOWTDI.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Less flippantly, inevitably the OP will want to format more than one value into the same string, so it's better to teach the syntax that generalizes more easily.

Comment: Sure, but then do so explicitly and talk about the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Calling string format functions is several times slower than

```py
>>> "%02d" % 8
'08'
>>> "%02d" % 80
'80'
```

So if you care about performance try to avoid function calls.

```
python -m timeit "'%02d' % 8"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0166 usec per loop

python -m timeit "'8'.zfill(2)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.163 usec per loop

python -m timeit "'{:02}'.format(2)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.385 usec per loop
```

In such simple and often called code, I would take the faster solution.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your direct question -

You can [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) your number like this:

```
format(num, '02d')
```

Example:

```
nums = [1,22,333]

for num in nums:
    print format(num, '02d')
```

Outputs:

```
01
22
333
```

However, you say that you are using a datetime. You can directly [format a datetime object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
%d - Zero padded day
%m - Zero padded month
```